# how can I access my web app in url after docker composer up -d

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-for-windows

Hi can you help me why I cannot see my page when I access in browser `app.dev` , it says unable to connect.I only see the echo in the console can you help me please in my docker-compose.yml and in my dockerfile what is missing. is my php is correct image ?

```
  version: "3.7"
services:

  web:
    build: .
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx-container
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    expose:
      - 9000
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/myapp
      - ./default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    links:
      - php
  php:
    image: php:7-fpm
    container_name: php-container

  db:
    image: mysql
    container_name: mysql-container
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpass
```

site.conf

```
   server {
        listen  80;
         index index.php;
         server_name app.dev;
         error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
         access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
         root /var/www/myapp;

         location ~ \.php$ {
                 try_files $uri =404;
                 fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
                 fastcgi_index index.php;
                 fastcgi_pass php:9000;
                 include fastcgi_params;
                 fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                 fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
             }
     }
```

dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.2-cli
COPY . /var/www/myapp
WORKDIR /var/www/myapp

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

entrypoint [ "php", "./index.php" ]
```

Comment: When you run `docker-compose up -d` what happens?

Comment: when i type localhost it shows nginx page

Comment: "when i type localhost it shows nginx page" <- that's what you're looking for

Comment: but i already edit the hostfile 
127.0.0.1 app.dev .still not showing the echo

Comment: Oh, but why is not the index.php ? I have index.php echo "Hello World my first docker"; but its not showing

Comment: @csminb , do I need Dockerfile to run my php web app ?

Comment: make sure the nginx image you're using contains php and check it's config file

Comment: @csminb, I added the site.conf is that correct ?

Comment: @jemz Don't you need a `listen 80` in your server block if you are mapping to port 80 in your docker-compose.yml file?

Comment: @dfundako I added now listen 80: when hit this app.dev browser says unable to connect

Comment: run `docker logs nginx-container` and see what's going on

Comment: after docker-compose up -d ? then docker logs nginx-container ? nothing happen no logs show in console and browser still unable to access

Comment: Try running without  `-d`, then you'll see the logs

Comment: @amorfis, i added the log now please check

Answer (score 0):

As I checked your `docker-compose.yaml` file:

You have mounted  you current path to `/var/www` which suppose to have projects files.

But `sit.conf`:

Configure the root document for Nginx to be `/` directory.

So what happens here is Nginx try to find `index.php` in `/` and when it can't find it uses the default configuration for Nginx and shows its default page.

To solve your issue:

Modify `site.conf` `root` to be `root /var/www/` and of course check the permissions and make sure it's right and it will work.